# Programming Mac Keys with Lua

Tags: macos, lua, hotkeys, logitech-gaming-software

So I'm pretty new to gaming and coding in general, but I've had some experience with iMacros (CSS and HTML, x/y) and Lua.

Because I need to be very mobile and so on, I'm not really looking for a gaming keyboard, instead I was hoping to be able to program my Mac's keys to do Lua programmed mouse clicks. 
I haven't found a way to do this so far.

I was thinking that I could create a separate user account and modify the keyboard on that, so the main keyboard is intact for daily use.

Note: I have looked into the one-handed gaming keypads - but those are still too big for my need. I am currently using the Logitech Proteus G502 mouse.

Note: Yes I know macs aren't ideal gaming computers. I use it for school and work and I prefer it over other laptops. The game I play is web based and I've had no issues so far.

Comment: Why do you need to modify your keyboard to program? You don’t need a gaming keyboard, but you need a keyboard. Programming on a Mac is completely normal.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

You said you are familiar with Lua. How did you program then? It was likely on a desktop - so its the same on a laptop. You just need to figure out what kind of programming you are wanting to do. Are you using Lua to script in games like Roblox? Roblox Studio is available on a Mac. General command-line programming? Open *Terminal* in Mac and you can program in most languages. Doing more serious programming? Then grt an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Eclipse. Try to narrow down specifically what you want to do and we can help you get set up.